# Using Kill command with a network path

Tags: ms-access, vba

I seem to be having a problem using the kill command to delete a file(s) when I use a network path, such as below wont work:

```
Kill "\\LAPTOP\SH-FOLDER\*.pdf"
```

If I give the full path name though, fine, no problems. Is there an issue with using network paths?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why your Kill command doesn't work.  This one works for me with Access 2003:

```
Kill "\\CMPQ\Access\*.txt"
```

Exactly what symptoms do you see?  Do you get an error message?

If you run this command in the Immediate Window, does it give you a file name back?

```
? Dir("\\LAPTOP\SH-FOLDER\*.pdf")
```

Comment: No i dont get any error message, it just doesn't perform the command. If i use MsgBox Dir("\\LAPTOP\SH-FOLDER\*.pdf") I get the first file alphabetically back.

Comment: I rechecked my code and my error handling was all wrong, i'm getting the error message "Error 75: Path/file access error". The files/folders aren't read only, not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @glinch Open a Command Prompt window and try `DEL \\LAPTOP\SH-FOLDER\*.pdf` ... with the same user account as the failing VBA Kill command.  What happens?  My best guess is you have a permission problem on the share or underlying file system, or some other user/process has a lock on the files you're trying to delete.

Comment: you were right on the money, Hadn't set up the sharing properties to allow network users to change files. Rookie mistake! Thanks for all your help.